# Destruction of a temporary object in C++

Tags: c++

I have two classes: `Vote` and `Voter`.

The class `Voter` has a constructor that receives two strings.

The class `Vote` has a constructor that receives an object from the class `Voter` and a string.

Now, I do the following:

```
Voter vr6("Cyprus", "Regular");
eurovision += Vote(vr6, "USA");
```

Where eurovision is an object from a class where I overloaded the `+=` operator.

From what I know, in the second line a temporary `Vote` object will be created.

My question is, how exactly is `vr6` affected from the destruction of the temporary object?

EDIT: The definition of the `Vote` constructor and destructor:

```
Vote(Voter current_voter, string state1, string state2 = "", string state3 = "", string state4 = "", string state5 = "", string state6 = "", string state7 = "", string state8 = "", string state9 = "", string state10 = "") :
        voter(current_voter), voted_state(new string[VOTE_ARRAY_SIZE]){
        voted_state[0] = state1;
        voted_state[1] = state2;
        voted_state[2] = state3;
        voted_state[3] = state4;
        voted_state[4] = state5;
        voted_state[5] = state6;
        voted_state[6] = state7;
        voted_state[7] = state8;
        voted_state[8] = state9;
        voted_state[9] = state10;
    }
    ~Vote() {
        delete[] voted_state;
    }
```

Comment: You should include the definition of the involved `Vote` constructor.

Comment: Incomplete code, impossible to say. If Vote() gets a Voter& , then it depends on the Vote() constructor. If it gets a Vote and Vote is properly copied, then vr6 won't be affected.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Why not just declare `string voted_state[10]` as a member variable in `Vote`? No need to `new` it and you then don't need to have a destructor.

Comment: What makes you think the destruction of the `Vote` temporary would have any effect on anything outside the temporary? From the code snippet in the question, all the destructor does is release memory allocated in the constructor. (Is there some relevant code you've chosen to not show us? Like the declaration of `Vote`?)

Comment: How `vr6` is affected depends on what the constructor and destructor of `Vote` do to it, and what the `operator+=()` does to it indirectly.   If `Vote`s constructor stores a reference to `vr6`, then the `operator+=()` uses that reference to clear all data in `vr6`, and `Vote`s destructor reformats the system hard drive if it finds all data is cleared, then that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass `vr6` by value to `Vote`'s constructor, the object in `vr6` itself will not depend on the `Vote` object's lifetime.
Note, however, that with the "call by value" a temporary copy of `vr6` will be created, and this copy will get deleted once the statement that calls `Vote`s constructor has ended.